# Convert Mysqli image array to a string for a Shopping cart

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, shopping-cart

I have a while loop that goes as follows

```
 while ($row_cat_pro = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat_pro)) {
     $pro_img = $row_cat_pro['product_image'];
     $pro_dollar = $row_cat_pro['product_price'];
 }
```

And the corresponding echo statements for the arrays goes as follows

```
 echo "<p>$pro_dollar</p>";
```

and

```
 echo "<img src='img/$product_img' />";
```

When I load the page Inspector, the `$pro_dollar` and `$pro_img` variables are both replaced with the word Array... How do I fix that?

**EDIT**

So far I've managed to fix one problem. I've surrounded the pro_dollar variable in the htmlentities function

ie

```
     $pro_dollar=htmlentities($row_cat_pro['pro_price']);
```

but I'm still stuck on the image variable...

Answer (score 0):

```
   $pro_dollar=$row_cat_pro['product_price']
```

$pro_dollar is an array and it can't be converted to string by just echoing it

to know key names use `print_r($pro_dollar);` then use extract to convert array keys into variables for example

```
// print_r() sample output

array (
"currency" => "USD"
)
```

by using `extract($pro_dollar);`

```
echo $currency; // outputs USD
```

Comment: So far it's not working.... Do I like, put the print_r function with the row_cat_pros in the while loop?